# Where can I pray if there is no prayer room

Tags: salat, practical-islam

Assalamualaikum

Do you guys have idea about room , spaces that you can use to pray if that place doesn't have any prayer room (musholla) . Like if I'm at school or at the mall or whatever. And there is no prayer room, where should i pray?

Answer (score 3):

The default is that you can pray anywhere. There is no obligation to pray in a place that is specially designated for prayer:

> وجعلت لنا الأرض كلها مسجدا
>
> the whole earth has been made a mosque for us
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:522a)</sup>

> حيثما أدركتك الصلاة فصل، والأرض لك مسجد
>
> Wherever the time for the prayer comes upon you, perform the prayer, for all the earth is a place of worshipping for you.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3425)</sup>

There are only exceptions in this rule where prayer is disliked for example a place where there is filth (bath, toilet, garbage dump, animal beds and slaughtering places) or a graveyard or in a church\temple of non-muslims or in the middle of a path where it blocks and hinders other people. Some of these are disagreed upon.

Comment: Good Answer. Jazzakk Allahu Khair.